# Convergence Warning Linear SVC — increase the number of iterations?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Here's the error I've been getting:

> ConvergenceWarning: Liblinear failed to converge, increase the number
> of iterations. warnings.warn("Liblinear failed to converge, increase "

I've been working with the romance and news categories in the brown dataset from nltk.corpus, and so far haven't had any issues up until this point. Here's the code that I'm putting in:

```html
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import brown
from nltk import pos_tag_sents
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import sklearn

for cat in brown.categories():
    print(cat)

news_sent = brown.sents(categories=["news"])
romance_sent = brown.sents(categories=["romance"])

ndf = pd.DataFrame({'label':'news', 'sentence':news_sent})
rdf = pd.DataFrame({'label':'romance', 'sentence':romance_sent})

df = pd.concat([ndf, rdf])

df.head()

df['label'].value_counts()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
_ = df['label'].value_counts().plot.bar(ax=ax, rot=0)
fig.savefig("categories_counts.png", bbox_inches = 'tight', pad_inches = 0)

pos_all = pos_tag_sents(df['sentence'])

def countPOS(pos_tag_sent, POS):
    pos_count = 0
    all_pos_counts = []
    for sentence in pos_tag_sent:
        for word in sentence:
            tag = word[1]
            if tag [:2] == POS:
                pos_count = pos_count+1
        all_pos_counts.append(pos_count)
        pos_count = 0
    return all_pos_counts

df['NN'] = countPOS(pos_all, 'NN')
df['JJ'] = countPOS(pos_all, 'JJ')

df.groupby('label').sum()

df.to_csv("df_news_romance.csv", index=False)

df = pd.read_csv("df_news_romance.csv")

fv = df[["NN", "JJ"]]

df['label'].value_counts()

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(fv, df['label'],
                                                stratify=df['label'],
                                                test_size=0.25,
                                                   random_state = 42)

print(X_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape)

from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
classifier = LinearSVC()

classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

At this point, I get the error above. To add more information from the original post, I've tried things like increasing max_iter and adding LinearSVC(dual=False), but no improvement. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set `LinearSVC(dual=False)`incase the number of samples in your data is more than the number of features. The original config of `LinearSVC` sets dual to `True` because its for solving the dual problem. Also you could try increasing the number of max iterations (e.g `max_iter=10000`).

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I had previously tried both of these solutions but no results. I tried them both again but still no improvement. Not sure what else to try.

Comment: scaling (normalization) could also help https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler